# getting error while connecting mongodb to code

Tags: database, mongodb

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://aryan:****@cluster0.vt72w0v.mongodb.net/' , {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
}).then(() => {
    console.log(`connection successfully done`);
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log("No connection");
});
```

This is the code, that i am looking for, to connect mongodb

One information that i have hided password with *** , so understand it.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to look for the code and Also, I have checked the configuration string
But I am clueless why it is not working

I am hoping to get a reasonable answer here.

Comment: `"No connection"` is  not a useful error message. Better use `console.log("No connection: " + e.message );` to see the real error.